# Change path before executing "SITE P_DEST" FTP command in WinSCP

Tags: c#, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

Is it possible to change path in WinSCP?
I know `session.PutFile(fileStream, '/general/incoming/Test.zip')` will write file at path mentioned. But when I try with command

```
CommandExecutionResult result = session.ExecuteCommand("SITE P_DEST KOMM@TEST");
```

It always have destination `/general/` (It is `session.HomePath`). Following is from session log:

```xml
<command value="SITE P_DEST KOMM@TEST" />
      <destination value="/general" />
```

Wonder is it possible to change path before executing command? I want to change path to `/general/Incoming`

Answer (score 3):

WinSCP .NET assembly does not use the concept of a working directory. It always uses absolute paths, as explained here:
[Change root SFTP directory using the WinSCP .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64067635/850848)

So when using the WinSCP API, you never need to change the working directory.

---

But ok, you are not using WinSCP API. You are seem to be trying to execute some proprietary command `SITE P_DEST` of your FTP server. You didn't tell us anything about that command. I do not know, what that does it do.

Let's guess that maybe your command works with FTP working directory. It seems that it connects somewhere. So I do not see, what does it have to do with a working directory. If it does, first make sure there's no way to tell the command, that it should use a different folder than the working directory. All standard FTP commands can do that.

If not, you can try to use `CWD /the/path` before `SITE P_DEST`.